# How to replaces space to new line in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have text file which contains many words (strings) separated by a space. How can I replace the spaces by newlines. In other words, how can I have each string on a different line in `bash`? I would be really grateful if one could also suggest a method using `sed`!

Answer (score 4):

A file bla:

```
a b    c d e
```

Using sed:

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' bla
```

Results in:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: Jack beat me to the punch so accept his answer. Note the way I wrote it outputs it to the terminal, while his method changes the file itself (with the bak)

Comment: Thank you Kabanus, yours was also really nice and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' file
```

`\s` will match any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, newlines), and `\+` will match on one or more occurrences in a row. `-i.bak` will backup your original file to `file.bak`.

Comment: Thank you Jack it was really helpful, especially knowing how to get a back up from the original file.

Comment: Than why don't you accept his solution? The V on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Few more ways:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foo bar   baz
a    433 5er
cat  fog try
```

using `xargs`

```
$ xargs -n1 < ip.txt 
foo
bar
baz
a
433
5er
cat
fog
try
```

using `grep`

```
$ grep -o '[^ ]*' ip.txt 
foo
bar
baz
a
433
5er
cat
fog
try
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat foo
a b  c
1   2 3
```

In Gnu awk (and mawk):

```
$ awk -v RS=" +|\n"  '{print $0}' foo
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

Using `tr` for a single line:

```
$ tr -s \  '\n' <<< "a b  c"
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thank you James and sorry for repeating the questions, I had googled my question but the other question was replacing coma with newline, and well google could not help me finding the previous post.

Comment: I am actually really intrigued that your suggestion is using awk. I could never thought of awk for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option:

```
echo "a b    c d e" | perl -pe 's/\s+/\n/g'
```